# program is packaged into an EXE include log4j2, an error occurs when the EXE software is run

Tags: java, maven, log4j, exe, noclassdeffounderror

Since POI relies on log4j 2.7.1, log4J-core and log4J-API have been added to Maven. There are no errors when the program is packaged as a JAR. An error occurs when using Exe4J to package the JAR into an EXE. . At first, I thought the log4j.xml configuration file didn't cause it, but it still didn't work when I put log4j.xml in the Resource folder. The development environment used is Win10 + ECplise 2022-03+ JDK17. Here is the error code:

```
WARNING: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass is not supported. This will impact performance.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/naming/Context
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.Interpolator.<init>(Interpolator.java:113)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.<init>(AbstractConfiguration.java:133)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:85)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getDefault(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:266)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:146)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:230)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:176)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getContext(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:54)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLoggerAdapter.getLogger(AbstractLoggerAdapter.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory.getLogger(Log4jLoggerFactory.java:33)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:285)
        at poitest.test.<clinit>(test.java:16)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(LauncherEngine.java:84)
        at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(WinLauncher.java:94)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.naming.Context
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
        ... 22 more
```

the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.poitest</groupId>
  <artifactId>poitest</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
              <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
              <version>5.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency> <!-- 桥接：告诉Slf4j使用Log4j2 -->
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency> <!-- 桥接：告诉commons logging使用Log4j2 -->
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build> 
    <finalName>test</finalName>
    <plugins>  
        <!-- define the project compile level -->  
        <plugin>  
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>  
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>  
            <version>2.3.2</version>  
            <configuration>  
                <source>17</source>  
                <target>17</target>  
            </configuration>  
        </plugin>  
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <transformers>/>
                            <!-- 指定启动类 -->
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>poitest.test</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>              
    </plugins>  
  </build> 

</project>
```

the program is:

```
package poitest;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hslf.usermodel.HSLFSlideShow;
import org.apache.poi.sl.extractor.SlideShowExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.extractor.XSLFExtractor;
import org.apache.poi.xslf.usermodel.XMLSlideShow;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class test {

    private final static Logger m_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("test");
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        m_logger.info("begin");
        test l_test = new test();
        m_logger.info("create test");
        String l_textString = l_test.ReadPPT("D:\\00\\chp02.pptx");
        m_logger.info("D:\\00\\chp02.pptx");
        System.out.println(l_textString);
        System.out.println( "End" ); 
        m_logger.info("end");

    }
    
    private String ReadPPT(final String n_FileName)
    {
        String l_text=new String("");
        try
        {
            File l_fileInfo=new File(n_FileName);
            if(l_fileInfo.length()<=0l)
            {
                //m_logger.info("ReadPPT ---{} is empty", n_FileName);
                return new String("");
            }
            FileInputStream l_file = new FileInputStream(l_fileInfo);
            if(n_FileName.endsWith(".ppt")||n_FileName.endsWith(".dps"))
            {                               
                HSLFSlideShow l_HSLFSlideShow = new HSLFSlideShow(l_file);
                SlideShowExtractor l_SlideShowExtractor = new SlideShowExtractor(l_HSLFSlideShow);
                l_text = l_SlideShowExtractor.getText();
                
            }
            else if(n_FileName.endsWith(".pptx"))
            {
                XMLSlideShow l_XMLSlideShow=new XMLSlideShow(l_file);
                XSLFExtractor l_XSLFExtractor= new XSLFExtractor(l_XMLSlideShow);
                l_text = l_XSLFExtractor.getText(); 
            }
            l_file.close();         
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            //m_logger.error("ReadPPT:{}  ----Exception-{}",n_FileName, e);
        }
        return l_text; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says it's unable to find `javax.naming.Context`, and the stack trace indicates that it's happening from within the Log4J [lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#) code.

I'm guessing that your logging config (which you don't show) includes `${jndi:something}`. The simplest solution will be to remove that lookup (and any others that start with `${jndi:`).

You could also look in the documentation for Exe4J to find out why it's not including the necessary classes (which are probably something referenced by `java.naming.Context`).

Beware that Log4J version 2.7.1 is vulnerable to Log4Shell. You should upgrade to the latest version for the version of Java that you're using (see [this](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html)).